# Django Admin permission just for inlines

Tags: django, admin

I have a ModelAdmin (A) that is an inline of another ModelAdmin (B).
I'd like to give Admin permissions (add, change and delete) to a User (U) just for A.
I gave to user every rights he needs (i think): is_staff: True | can add, change, delete A.
The problem is that U can't see the inline A on the admin panel. If i give him also permissions for B it works but i don't want to let him to modify that model.
There is a sort of "readonly" for model B in these cases?

Answer (score 1):

The admin interface is for editing, if you want to allow some users to edit model A but not model B add A as a ModelAdmin and allows only those users to manage(Add,Edit,Delete) Model A.

```
class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

class AInline(GenericTabularInline):
    model = A
    ...

class BAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        AInline,
    ]
    ...     

admin.site.register(A, AAdmin)
admin.site.register(B, BAdmin)



a_user.user_permissions.add('my_app.add_a', 'my_app.change_a', 'my_app.delete_a')
b_user.user_permissions.add('my_app.add_b', 'my_app.change_b', 'my_app.delete_b')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i got the point! Just for future users i think you had a mistake on writing inlines = [BInline,]...think you wanted write inlines = [AInline,]